# Blender:Cycles:Nodes:Input:Geometry:Position corrupts displacement mapping - bug or misconfig?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

See below image for clarification.

Not only is the geometry not being displaced properly, it seems to have distorted (mirrored?) the Surface color mapping too. The only thing that changes from the first and second screenshot is the connection: Texture.Fac --> Displacement.

Note that both planes have the same material, and that the second plane is transformed in object mode.

Tested in blender 2.74 - should i file a bug report?

[image: Bug Illustration]

Comment: The checker texture is generated texture in 3D space, try to separate XYZ coordinates from position input to Z only

Comment: I think there might be something else going on in your scene. The colors you have in the checker texture would not produce the black and white in the render. Further, is it a subdivided plane? Are you using the experimental feature set? If so, is the displacement set to *True* or *both*? DO you have any modifiers on that object?

Comment: @David : It's subdivided by subsurf modifier (you can see the plane at the origin displaces properly), I'm using the experimental set on the default scene.

It works properly if i transform the coordinates of the second plane in edit-mode instead of object-mode. I tried playing with object-viewspace transformations on the input coordinates but they don't cause the right behavior.

Comment: @Denis : The Z-only channel into the texture just produces a black surface for me.

Comment: I mean X and Y only, that way its will be same colors along Z axis

Comment: @Denis : that fixes the problems with the color map (the left side top-down view looks correct) but the displacement is still being performed wrong (rotation doesn't match).

Comment: it seems that the displacement is using the object local coordinates to apply the displacement